# Illustrator / Photoshop Color Profiles

Tags: colors, adobe-illustrator, eps

I found out recently that I can get my colors 1:1 for print, in photoshop, if I assign the profile: Photoshop 5 Default CMYK

However, at this point Im doing a different project that needs to be saved in EPS form from illustrator. I can get the jpg from photoshop to Illustrator and if I do this in Illustrator: Edit > Assign Profile > photoshop 5 Default CMYK, it will look exactly like it does in Photoshop. My only problem is that it will not save this way. It seems that when I save as EPS, it looses that Photoshop 5 Default CMYK color profile, and the end result(EPS) is less saturated.

Anyone have tips on how to save as EPS from Illustrator with the Photoshop 5 Default CMYK color profile?

THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embed or attach an ICC profile to an EPS file, because PostScript does not support ICC profiles.

It sounds like Illustrator is not **applying** the profile, merely using it to display the result. I'd guess this is an RGB JPEG image ?

If so then I think the best approach is to tell Photoshop to convert the JPEG colour space from RGB to CMYK and save the JPEG that way. Of course, this will involve re-quantising the image data, which will introduce artefacts that you may find objectionable.

If the image is already CMYK then you will somehow need to persuade Photoshop to convert the existing CMYK components to the ones which you see when you apply the CMYK profile. This will also likely introduce quantising artefacts.

To be honest this isn't really a PostScript question, more of a colour management or image manipulation problem.

Comment: Thank you Ken! Your right it seems EPS is not attaching the Profile, seems PDF doesn't either. I did save as PNG and that works. The thing is Im working with a $30,000 Roland printer and if I save a spot color named "CutContour" I can do custom cut lines. The file needs to be saved as EPS to be able to do the custom cut function. Tomorrow I'll call the printer tech to find out if there is another file type the printer will accept that can use both the CutContour function and accepts ICC Profiles. Im using the VersaWorks Software

Comment: You can put an ICC profile in a PDF file, but that doesn't mean that a PDF consumer will pay attention to it! I presume the image doesn't hav a spot colour, so presumably you're adding that in Illustrator. Is there a reason why you can't load the PNG into Illustrator and add the contour to that, then save as an EPS ?